# vscode remote ssh with Linux has a memory issue

Tags: linux, memory, build, nuxt.js, vscode-remote-ssh

Im using VSCODE remote ssh to connect Linux server.

and I sometimes build nuxt project and sometimes stop build process because of memory.

(PID 17984 is nuxt project.)

there are 6 processes about VSCODE remote ssh, even and They have much memory.

(PID 13904, 7189, 19743, 19772, 16850, 7242)

now, vscode process's RSS is 200-500MB so it is fine.

but sometimes vscode process's RSS became to 2000MB.

so server became too slow.

How can I fix this vscode remote ssh memory issue?

[image: memory status]

[image: memory using status of top 15 processes]

Comment: Hm, it's pretty hard to know what is happening on that VPS without further investigation on your part. So, the total of memory usage by the Nuxt app is fluctuating? Make sure that you have properly cleaned any processes related to a past running Nuxt app. Try to replicate it locally on your machine too. Double that it's not coming from PM2 too.

Comment: Btw, does it happen if you have a regular simpler SSH connection?

Answer (score 2):

My setup is to work on a remote machine with docker-compose. Sometimes, it may be related to your extensions. I'm using remote container + remote SSH, Python, and Pylance extensions.

When I use all of them. They used up my 2GB Ram + 1vCPU. The instance was frozen and I had to reboot the dev machine. After that, I stopped the Python and Pylance extensions in the container and the Ram & CPU usage were lowered.

In my case, the linter is the cause. It keeps loading in the remote machine when I was coding. Without the Python & Pylance extensions, I can't work well but it's another issue.

Hope VS Code team can fix the memory usage issue.

Comment: my amazon ec2 instance also starts freezing & get frozen aftr 10-15 minustes of connecting vscode ssh.

Comment: Your instance may not have enough RAMs. 2GB Ram is the minimum but vs code is still slow.

Answer (score 1):

try to uninstall your extensions one by one to find the one that cause the leak. for my case I have found PHP debugger extension make CPU 100%

Comment: That probably should be a comment rather.

Comment: Question referred to excessive memory use, not CPU.

Comment: This does not make the answer any less valid; the statement is one of example, extensions can leak memory.